# Error: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request

Tags: java, spring, request, resteasy

Good afternoon community, I find this error when consuming a service, I have reviewed other articles published in this medium but I cannot find the solution to my problem

This is my main

```
public class MainConsume {

  
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String res = "";
        String URL = "http://127.0.0.1:20001/claro-int-consultacliente-resource/api/int/consultacliente/v1.0.0/consultarContratos";

        try {

            Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
            WebTarget target = client.target(URL);
            Invocation.Builder solicitud = target.request();
            MultivaluedMap<String, Object> myHeaders = new MultivaluedHashMap<String, Object>();
            myHeaders.add("1111111122332223456", "idTransaccion");
            myHeaders.add("0", "msgid");
            myHeaders.add("0", "userid");
            solicitud.headers(myHeaders);
            request req = new request();
            req.setTipoDocumento("2");
            req.setNumeroDocumento("74163187");
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String jsonString = gson.toJson(req);
            System.out.println(jsonString);
            Response post = solicitud.post(Entity.json(jsonString));
            String responseJson = post.readEntity(String.class);
            res = responseJson;

            System.out.println("Estatus: " + post.getStatus());

            switch (post.getStatus()) {
                case 200:
                    res = responseJson;
                    break;
                default:
                    res = "Error";
                    break;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            res = e.toString();
        }

        System.out.println(res);

    }

}
```

This is my pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>pe.claro</groupId>
    <artifactId>consumeservicios</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <!-- add Main-Class to manifest file -->
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>pe.claro.com.eai.consumeservicios.MainConsume</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180130</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Please change the line `res = e.toString();` to `e.printStackTrace();` so we can see more information.  Include that information in an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70930622/edit) of your post.

Comment: That is a fairly old version of RESTEasy too. You may want to consider upgrading especially since this is just client code.